# Angularjs: Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, service, promise

So I'm trying to do a call inside an angular service:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('ebs-front').service('NotificationHelper', function(TransactionService, $q) {
    this.IsNewTransaction = function(employeeId) {        
        debugger;
        TransactionService.pendingForEmployee({ employeeId: 2 }).$promise.then(function(result) {
            TransactionService.isNewTransaction({ id: result.id }).$promise.then(function(result) {
                debugger;
                return result;
            });
        });
    };
});
```

In `pendingForEmployee` I need to retrieve some data, and the call `isNewTransaction` with the result of that call. I want to return this data in my controller:

```
NotificationHelper.IsNewTransaction({employeeId: $stateParams.id}).$promise.then(function(res) {
    debugger;
    NotificationManager.Register('success', res.isNewTransaction);
    $state.go('root.sidebar.employee-dashboard', { id: $stateParams.id }, {reload: true});
});
```

My problem is that I keep getting an error, and I got no idea how to solve this:

```
Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined.
```

The exception occurs in this line of my controller:

```
NotificationHelper.IsNewTransaction({employeeId: $stateParams.id}).$promise.then(function(res)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `NotificationHelper.IsNewtransaction` actually returns something?

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I keep getting an error, and I got no idea how to solve this:

Of course, because `NotificationHelper.IsNewTransaction` doesn't return anything, so actually it implicetly returns `undefined`.

Make sure your function returns a promise if you want to use Promise API. Maybe in your case `return TransactionService.pendingForEmployee(...)`:

```
angular.module('ebs-front').service('NotificationHelper', function(TransactionService, $q) {
    this.IsNewTransaction = function(employeeId) {
        return TransactionService.pendingForEmployee({ employeeId: 2 }).$promise.then(function(result) {
            return TransactionService.isNewTransaction({ id: result.id }).$promise.then(function(result) {
                return result;
            });
        });
    };
});
```

or you can shorten it to:

```
angular.module('ebs-front').service('NotificationHelper', function(TransactionService, $q) {
    this.IsNewTransaction = function(employeeId) {
        return TransactionService.pendingForEmployee({ employeeId: 2 }).$promise.then(function(result) {
            return TransactionService.isNewTransaction({ id: result.id }).$promise;
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Huh, I need the result from TransactionService.isNewTransaction, so my thought was to return result which is a resource. I also tried return result.$promise, but the result was the same. I spend a couple of hours trying to research, but with no result. I'm kinda puzzled on how to return the result of TransactionService.isNewTransaction to my controller...

Comment: So I tried this:this.IsNewTransaction = function(employeeId) {        

        debugger;
        TransactionService.pendingForEmployee({ employeeId: 2 }).$promise.then(function(result) {
            return TransactionService.isNewTransaction({ id: result.id });

        });
    };

And still I get an error: vendor.js:23068 TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined. I honestly got no idea on how to fix this....

Comment: One more time: you need to return promise from `NotificationHelper.IsNewTransaction`. Currently you are returning `undefined`.

Comment: I get that: the result from TransactionService.isNewTransaction({ id: res.id }); is a resource. How should I write my code to return a promise?!

Comment: No success, error on this line in my controller:
 NotificationHelper.IsNewTransaction({employeeId: $stateParams.id}).$promise.then(function(res) {

With your first answer I get:
vendor.js:23068 TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

And with your second answer I get:
vendor.js:23068 TypeError: Cannot read property '$promise' of undefined

Comment: I suggest then creating a simple demo in plunkr.